# Flowplayer disable autoplay with OVA

Tags: javascript, flowplayer, vast

I have a problem which is probably easy to solve but i has not yet found a solution. I try to initialize Flowplayer with the OVA (Ad management) plugin. If I set the parameter "autoPlay" = false on a clip the player won't autoplay on initialization. Just as I wan't it. However, if I have, let's say a pre-roll, managed by the OVA plugin it will play once you hit the Play button. But once the pre-roll has finished the main clip won't autoplay. The user has to hit "Play" again.

So the question is: How do I use Flowplayer with OVA and the player shouldn't autoplay until the user hits "Play" but once a pre-roll (or any other ad) has played it should continue to the next clip?

```
flowplayer( "elementID", "flowplayer.commercial-3.2.15.swf",
    {
        clip:
        {
            url: "video.mp4",
            autoPlay: false
        },
        plugins:
        {
            ova:
            {
                url: "ova.swf",
                ads:
                {
                    schedule:
                    [
                        {
                            position: "pre-roll",
                            server:
                            {
                                type: "direct",
                                tag: "vast.url"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's too late for a response, but for the ones visiting this post henceforth, the answer is to put `autoPlay:false` inside the `"ova"` object, instead of the `"clip"` one:

```
ova: {
    url: "ova.swf",
    autoPlay: false,
    // ----- "general" options here -----
}
```